# React-router with createBrowserHistory for partial and full page reloads

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use react-router v1.0.0 for full page and partial reloadable urls. 
I have the following "History.jsx" file,

```jsx
import BrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

export default new BrowserHistory();
```

and I import it in my main entry file "app.jsx" like following,

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Router from 'react-router';
import Routes from './../utils/Routes.jsx';
import history from './../utils/History.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
    (<Router history={history}>{Routes}</Router>),
    document.getElementById('pageSpecific')
);
```

Now when i navigate to "localhost:8080", it shows the page good. When i click on a href in the page, it takes to "localhost:8080/example" correctly without the "#" in the URL and it does not reload the page. Its all good.

Now that my URL is "localhost:8080/example" and when i try to refresh the page, it says "cannot get /example". This is problem which i am not able to solve!

Am i doing anything wrong? I am really struck in this place!!

Comment: Well your http server is trying to server is trying to give you a file called example, but not finding it, resulting in a 404. You need to configure url rewrites on your http server. How to do that is based on what http server you're using.

Comment: ok, got it. So its something to do with my server rather than the react-router?